# Bitbucket pipeline custom cache definition not working

Tags: bitbucket, pipeline, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a project with two sub folders. Here's the structure:

```
src
|- api
|- ui
    |-node_modules
bitbucket-pipelines.yml
```

Since my node modules folder is not in the same directory as the pipeline file, I tried creating a definition and included the path. Here's where I'm trying to cache it in my pipeline:

```
pipelines:
  default:
      - step:
          name: "Frontend"
          image: node:14.17.1
          caches:
            - frontendnode
          script:
            - cd src/ui
            - npm install 
            - CI=false npm run build
definitions:
  caches:
    frontendnode: src/ui/node_modules
```

My guess is that my definition is wrong but I have tried multiple things and I'm getting the same error:

```
Assembling contents of new cache 'frontendnode'
Cache "frontendnode": Skipping upload for empty cache
```

Thanks!

Comment: `src/ui/node_modules` was the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to print all files of machine, call:

```
apt-get install -y tree
tree
```

Also cache will fill after success complete of pipeline

Or your `src/ui/node_modules` folder is empty

Comment: I was struggling with cache not working for couple of hours until I found this answer. The key was "Also cache will fill after success complete of pipeline".
I was testing the pipeline with failing npm tests.